Access token and other returned args separated in return uri by # instead of?
I'm new to working with the docusign API and am using implicit grant. It's working, but is returning the arguments to my return uri (which is just a regular url and path) with a # as the delimiter - indicating an anchor in the specified page - rather than a ? which has been used for decades to indicate search args? It goes on to separate the "search args" (if that's what they still are) by & as is the standard, but because they've replaced the ? with #, it's proving impossible for me to get those args. How are others dealing with this? Why would they do that?
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature&client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=https://[myurl] where [my_client_id] and [myurl] are replaced with the appropriate values. There is sometimes a login required, but after login (or sometimes straight away, if login is not needed by docusign), docusign returns arguments to [myurl] as #access_token=[token]&expires_in=28800&token_type=bearer&scope=signature where [token] is replaced with an access_token like I would expect, but how do I get it if it's not designated as a search arg? If the # was a ? this would not be a problem.

When using the Implicit Grant, it should only be applied in scenarios where a single-page web application cannot ensure the security of sensitive information. This flow is appropriate when neither the Authorization Code Grant nor JWT are viable options.
Regarding your query, the URL fragment is managed on the client side by JavaScript and is not transmitted to the server. It’s intended for use within the browser. The Implicit Grant flow employs the fragment because it is designed to be client-side, unlike the Authorization Code Grant, which involves setting up a backend server and uses the query string for communication. DocuSign does block fragments in returnUris, and shouldn’tt be able to add them anymore
For your integration, it’s crucial to capture the complete URL. This JavaScript can be used as a reference.
let url = "https://httpbin.org/get#access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE>&expires_in=28800&token_type=bearer&scope=signature"

url.split("#")

let params = new URLSearchParams(url[1])

let json = Object.fromEntries(params.entries())

// result
{
    "access_token": "<ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE>",
    "expires_in": "28800",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": "signature"
}

Best,
DocuSign Dev/API team

Thank you. I spoke with a member of your team and they instructed me to use the JWT version, but that comes with its own challenge, as RSASHA256(
base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
base64UrlEncode(body),
"<your_public_RSA_key>",
"<your_private_RSA_key>"
) is a misleading format for a JWT signature. JWT is signed by private key only. I'm generating that via line command, but private key should need need to be re-entered for validation at https://jwt.io/. Your demos show "generating" JWT with jwt.io, but jwt.io is supposed to be a validator.
